# Deutsch's algorithm in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, nielsen-and-chuang, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I am trying to understand and implement the Deutsch algorithm. I follow the logic from Nielsen book and I started to implement it in Qiskit. 
For implementing the oracle, I use a CNOT gate and now I have this circuit:

[image]

Every time I ran it, the first qubit is always in state $|1\rangle$.
I am not sure if this is what I expect. Shouldn't it be sometimes $|1\rangle$ and sometimes $|0\rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNOT gate is an example that implements a balanced function for which $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$:

\begin{equation}
CNOT \frac{1}{2}\left(|0\rangle + |1\rangle \right) \left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle \right) =
\\
= \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle \left(|0 \oplus f(0)\rangle - |1 \oplus f(0)\rangle \right) 
+ \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle \left(|0 \oplus f(1)\rangle - |1 \oplus f(1)\rangle \right) =
\\
= \frac{1}{2} \left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle \right) \left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle \right)
\end{equation}

$$H \otimes I \frac{1}{2}\left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle \right) \left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle \right)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle \left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle \right)$$

It means that if we will do everything right we always should obtain (for balanced functions $f(0) \ne f(1)$) $|1\rangle$ outcome in the Deutsch algorithm.

For more look at 1.44 equation (page 33) in the M. Nielsen and I. Chuang textbook, where one can find the final state before the measurement. In the 1.44 system, one can see that if $f(0) = f(1)$ then the first qubit  will be in $|0\rangle$ state and if $f(0) \ne f(1)$ (like the case with CNOT) then the first qubit will be in $|1\rangle$ state before the measurement.

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much. You are right. So as I can understand, there is no way to implement the algorithm, without knowing f(0) and f(1), because I will need a different oracle for each case.

Comment: @marissalianam, you are welcome :). You are right, I think the comments of this answer can be interesting: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/10084/9459
Also here you can find implementations for the other functions:
https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9566/implementing-four-oracles-for-the-deutsch-algorithm-preferably-on-ibm-q-experie